# Using SAM deploy or Cloudformation deploy in CodeBuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codebuild

I am New to CodeBUild and i am trying to package and deploy a lambda function . I have my builspec.yaml file and its contents are as below :

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:

  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo "[Pre-Build phase]"

  build:
    commands:
      - aws cloudformation package --template-file template.yaml --s3-bucket <bucketname> --output-template-file packaged.yaml
      - aws s3 cp ./packaged.yaml s3://testbucketdemo/packaged.yaml
      - aws s3 cp s3://testbucketdemo/packaged.yaml C:\codebuild\tmp\output

  post_build:
    commands:
      - aws cloudformation deploy --template-file C:\codebuild\tmp\output\packaged.yaml --stack-name testcvdg

artifacts:
  type: zip
  files:
    - packaged.yaml
```

My template.yaml looks like below:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Description: "My API Gateway and Lambda function"

Parameters:
  apiGatewayStageName:
    Type: "String"
    AllowedPattern: "^[a-z0-9]+$"
    Default: "dev"

  lambdaFunctionName:
    Type: "String"
    AllowedPattern: "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"
    Default: "my-function"

Resources:
  apiGateway:
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi"
    Properties:
      Name: "cf-DBTableScheduling"
      Description: "DBTableScheduling-apigateway by CF"

  dbconn:
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Resource"
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref apiGateway
      ParentId: !GetAtt 
        - apiGateway
        - RootResourceId
      PathPart: dbconn



  apiGatewayRootMethod:
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Method"
    Properties:
      AuthorizationType: "NONE"
      HttpMethod: "POST"
      Integration:
        IntegrationHttpMethod: "POST"
        Type: AWS
        Credentials: "arn:aws:iam::1231544:role/ApiGatewayInvokeLambdaRole"
        Uri: !Sub
          - "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${lambdaArn}/invocations"
          -  lambdaArn: "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:123154878:function:Lambda-DBConnMgmtFunction-3T876IRCHJJGHJG"
      ResourceId: !Ref "dbconn" 
      RestApiId: !Ref "apiGateway"
      MethodResponses:
        - StatusCode: 200
          ResponseParameters:
            method.response.header.Content-Type: true

  apiGatewayDeployment:
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment"
    DependsOn:
      - "apiGatewayRootMethod"
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref "apiGateway"
      StageName: !Ref "apiGatewayStageName"

  DBConnMgmtFunctionTesting:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: DBConnMgmtFunction
      Handler: com.test.dbconnmgmt.lambda.DBConnMgmtLambda::handleRequest
      Runtime: java8
      FunctionName: !Ref "lambdaFunctionName"
      MemorySize: 1024
      Policies: AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess
      Environment:
        Variables:
          REGION: us-east-2
          DYNAMODB_NAME: DBConnectionInfo

  lambdaLogGroup:
    Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
    Properties:
      # LogGroupName: !Sub "/aws/lambda/${DBConnMgmtFunctionTesting}"
      LogGroupName: !Join 
        - ''
        - - /aws/lambda/
          - !Ref lambdaFunctionName
      RetentionInDays: 90

Outputs:
  apiGatewayInvokeURL:
    Value: !Sub "https://${apiGateway}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/${apiGatewayStageName}"
```

Now this works evertime if i run the project. But everytime i need to copy the output file packaged.yaml to S3 and then  again from S3 to some path that cloudformation can use , as after cloudformation package the output gets saved to some path like  C:\codebuild\tmp\output\src169630847\src\github.com\naoleyrashmi\dgweyy\packaged.yaml and if i directly use aws cloudformation deploy --template-file packaged.yaml --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM --stack-name testcvdg , the cloudformation doesnt get the package.yaml. Is there any clear way of using this ?. I even tried using SAM by using sam build and sam deploy but even here the sam deploy would ask me to confirm the changeset and there is no way to supress this or set changeset to Y . Can anyone please help here.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by " the cloudformation doesnt get the package.yaml". Can you clarify. Also can you provide the contents of the template.yaml you are trying to deploy

Comment: I think what you want is to reference the [codebuild environment variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-env-vars.html). If you reference the  `CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR` variable when you deploy, you will be able to remove the s3 copying since you will know where it is each time.

Comment: Thanks Ben so do you suggest me using CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR while deploying ? would something like below work ?   aws cloudformation deploy --template-file $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR\packaged.yaml --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM --stack-name teststack

Comment: That more or less what I would do. Haven't tested it myself, but it may look like $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR\github.com\naoleyrashmi\dgweyy\packaged.yaml. You can test you codebuild by outputting the contents of the directory to verify.

Comment: I tried it but didnt work unfortunately . Here i am deploying in build phase instead of using code Deploy, that might be the issue . I would update this in case i get any links . Thanks